# Updating a Users Join Date?

Tags: users, import

I'm doing a big import of users from an EE install using the Import plugin. I can pull in all the details I need except the join date, so I looked at the craft db to see where it needs to be changed.

I successfully managed to change it by updating the `craft_elements` table, `dateCreated` column. This changed the join date in the control panel, however it does update the `dateCreated` column in the `craft_users` table so I updated there also.

Just wondering if thats correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that's correct. The `craft_elements.dateCreated` column is the one that is referenced by the user's Join Date.

For the sake of being thorough, I prefer to copy that same value into `craft_users.dateCreated`, just as you have done.

Comment: That's great Lindsey, thanks. I don't suppose your familiar with the Import plugin? I'm wondering whether this can be adapted to update the join date when importing? It would obviously need to update it in both places.

Comment: Sounds like a good [feature request](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/issues). Or even better, make the adjustment yourself and submit it as a pull request! Bob loves PR's.

Comment: Yea, I've requested it on Github. Doesn't seem to be much activity on it at the moment. Perhaps in the new year.  
I did try amending the plugin myself, but what ever I did didn't seem to make a difference. (Not familiar with plugin dev at all.)